# Why is angular type "Routes" mutable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to make the `routes` passed to the Angular `Router` a constant so that I can have IntelliSense for all possible route paths:

```
const route = [
  { path: 'my-path', component: MenuItemsComponent },
  { path: 'my-path', component: MenuItemsComponent },
] as const;
const myRoutes = route as Routes;
```

Typescript says I can't do this, it throws this error:

```
Conversion of type 'readonly [{ readonly path: "my-path"; readonly component: typeof MenuItemsComponent; }, { readonly path: "my-path"; readonly component: typeof MenuItemsComponent; }]' to type 'Routes' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  The type 'readonly [{ readonly path: "my-path"; readonly component: typeof MenuItemsComponent; }, { readonly path: "my-path"; readonly component: typeof MenuItemsComponent; }]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Routes'.
```

But why is `Routes` a mutable type? I can't understand.

## Edit

To explain why i need const, is because in with consts we can do that:

```
type Path = typeof route[number]['path'];
```

So now i can restrict a variable to a path declared in the router.

Comment: Routes is an array, which is mutable by default (because you can use `.push()` etc on it)

Comment: Take a look at the "Writable" helper interface they have created here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-mapped-type-modifiers-and-readonly-arrays

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test on my local and your code compiles fine with Angular 11.

If your real concern is auto complete in your IDE; then you can try a conversion, like this:

```
const route: routes = [
  { path: 'my-path', component: MenuItemsComponent } as Route,
  { path: 'my-path', component: MenuItemsComponent } as Route,
] as const;
```

And I get AutoComplete in IntelliJ:

[image]

An alternate option might be to create your own class that extends the Route interface and use that to create your own Route interfaces.

Generally like this:

```
export class MyRouteClass extends Route {
  path?: string
  pathMatch?: string
  matcher?: UrlMatcher
  component?: Type<any>
  redirectTo?: string
  outlet?: string
  canActivate?: any[]
  canActivateChild?: any[]
  canDeactivate?: any[]
  canLoad?: any[]
  data?: Data
  resolve?: ResolveData
  children?: Routes
  loadChildren?: LoadChildren
  runGuardsAndResolvers?: RunGuardsAndResolvers
}
```

and then:

```
const route: routes = [
  Object.assign(new MyRouteClass(), { path: 'my-path', component: MenuItemsComponent }),
  Object.assign(new MyRouteClass(), { path: 'my-path', component: MenuItemsComponent }),
];
```